# How to close a modal form and all the modal forms that were opened from it?

Tags: delphi, modal-dialog, delphi-5

Real life example: My application has a MainForm. The user can click on a button and login to see the modal AdminSettingsForm. From the AdminSettingsForm, he can open even more modal forms and so on.

When the user logs in to show the AdminSettingsForm, a timer is started, which should close the AdminSettingsForm after a period of inactivity (idleness).

I tried this:

```
 for i := Screen.FormCount - 1 downto 1 do begin
   if Screen.Forms[i] <> MainForm then begin
     Screen.Forms[i].Close();
   end;
 end;
```

Nothing happens until I close the topmost modal form, then everything else instantly closes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry, but I think I already found a solution:

```
 Screen.ActiveForm.Close();

 for i := Screen.FormCount - 1 downto 1 do begin
   if Screen.Forms[i] <> MainForm then begin
     Screen.Forms[i].Close();
   end;
 end;
```

Seems to work...

Comment: This assumes that all forms other than `MainForm` will be for administrative use. What if you ever create a new form for a non-administrative users?

Comment: You are correct. This assumption currently holds true for my application. Actually I do have other forms for non-admin users, but there's another assumption that any form triggered from MainForm is modal. So currently I know that when the AdminForm shows, no other forms are visible. I'll break my head for a better solution when this assumption does not hold anymore.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
with Screen do
     for I := FormCount - 1 downto 0 do
       if Forms[I] <> Application.MainForm then
           Forms[I].Close;
```